# Dialog.setOnDismissListener NullpointerException

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, bottom-sheet

If I try to run the following code, I receive

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface$OnDismissListener)' on a null object reference
```

(error in  bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener() )

The same code works in another fragment, so I do not know what I am doing wrong here.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new MediaImportFragment();
bundle.putString("url", sharedText);
bottomSheetDialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
bottomSheetDialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        onResume();
                    }
                });
```

Greetings,
Battlestr1k3